# Insert one table into another (from different databases) – MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

How can I insert one table (the whole not just a few variables) into another (from different databases)? I have already tried it, but can't really figure out, where the problem is or what queries I have to write that it works.

```html
CREATE DATABASE hr_employment_new;

CREATE TABLE hr_employment_NEW; 

insert into hr_employment_NEW VALUES();
select*
from sys.HR_Employment;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE DATABASE hr_employment_new LIKE sys.HR_Employment;
INSERT INTO hr_employment_new (SELECT * FROM sys.HR_Employment);
```

Comment: So how would I then copy all the data from "sys.HR_Emplyment" into a new database respectively into a new table?

Comment: @Carla.K That's what the `INSERT` statement does.

Comment: This *does* copy indexes.

Comment: But when I write it like this: -- Create new DB, Use table from DB "sys"
CREATE DATABASE hr_employment_db LIKE sys.HR_Employment;
USE hr_employment_db;

INSERT INTO hr_employment (SELECT * FROM sys.HR_Employment);

-- Read
SELECT*FROM hr_employment;

Comment: There appears an error code "1064", which says that I have an error in my SQL syntax (a red line is under the word LIKE)